# VB.Net WPF ComboBox - Unselect Item

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, reset, selecteditem

I have a ComboBox in a WPF program.  It is bound to a list of strings that come from a SQL query.  When I run the program the ComboBox starts out blank (selectedIndex = -1).  After I choose an item from the ComboBox, all I can do is keep that item or select a different one.  But, I am not able to use the delete key to clear the selection.  Is there a way to bind the Delete key to the combobox so that it clears the selection (sets SelectedIndex back to  -1)?

Comment: Users are expected to type something in the `ComboBox` control to easily find an item, not to remove/add items. You would have to implement this functionality yourself (e.g., via button "delete" + `yourComboBox.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex)`).

Comment: @varocarbas I am not trying to remove items from the combobox.  Just to clear the selection.  In my application I will sometimes need to have no item selected.

Comment: If the user deletes the selection, it should be kept blank. Also you might do `yourComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1` (at least in Winforms, I think that in WPF is the same). Alternatively, you might add a starting blank item and use it for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bindings, you can do it like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbo1" SelectedIndex="{Binding CboSelectedIndex}" >
    <ComboBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding SetSelectedIndex}"/>
    </ComboBox.InputBindings>
</ComboBox>
```

And the command "SetSelectedIndex" would set the dependency property "CboSelectedIndex" to be -1.

With code behind you could have something like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbo1"/>
```

Code-behind (after InitializeComponent()):

```
Dim command As New ActionCommand(Sub()
                                     cbo1.SelectedIndex = -1
                                 End Sub)

cbo1.InputBindings.Add(New KeyBinding(command, New KeyGesture(Key.Delete)))
```

Needless to say the "ActionCommand" is a standard/boiler-plate implementation of ICommand:

```
Public Class ActionCommand
    Implements ICommand
    Private ReadOnly _action As Action
    Public Sub New(action As Action)
        _action = action
    End Sub
    Private Function ICommand_CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
        Return True
    End Function
    Private Sub ICommand_Execute(parameter As Object) Implements ICommand.Execute
        _action()
    End Sub
    Public Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler
    Private Event ICommand_CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, I will implement this.  For now what I've done is created a handler for the right click mouse down event, but it wouldn't be very intuitive for the user.  This will be much better.